# Thrust: Computing set_difference of multiple segments in parallel

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I have written some code to compute a set_difference per segment using thrust. The idea is to use additional arrays to indicate which element belongs to which segment, and a custom comparator.
This produces the correct output sets, but the output segment sizes are wrong if an input segment is empty. Reduce-by-key is used to count the number of elements per segment using the output segment identifiers per element. If a input segment is empty, the corresponding segment id does not appear in the output segment ids which causes wrong results.

Correct:

```
segmentsizesLeft {4,3}
segmentIdsLeft {0,0,0,0,1,1,1}

outputsegmentIds {0,0,0,1}
outputsegmentsizes {3,1}
```

Wrong:

```
segmentsizesLeft {0,3}
segmentIdsLeft {1,1,1}

outputsegmentIds {1}
outputsegmentsizes {1, uninitialized} //should be {0,1}
```

How can this be solved?

```
#include <thrust/set_operations.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/tuple.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/constant_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/discard_iterator.h>

#include <iostream>

int main(){

    //compute set_difference(left, right) , per segment
    //output: contiguous range of remaining elements, array of output segment sizes

#if 1    
    //correct result
    int numLeft = 7;
    int dataLeft[7]{0,1,2,3, 1,3,4};
    int segmentsizesLeft[2]{4,3};
    int psLeft[3]{0,4,7};
    int segmentIdsLeft[7]{0,0,0,0,1,1,1};
#else 
    //wrong result. empty input segment is no longer present in output segment sizes
    int numLeft = 3;
    int dataLeft[3]{1,3,4};
    int segmentsizesLeft[2]{0,3};
    int psLeft[3]{0,0,3};
    int segmentIdsLeft[3]{1,1,1};
#endif    
 
    int dataRight[7]{2, 3,4};
    int segmentsizesRight[2]{1,2};
    int psRight[3]{0,1,3};
    int segmentIdsRight[3]{0,1,1};

    auto first1 = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(&segmentIdsLeft[0], &dataLeft[0]));
    auto last1 = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(&segmentIdsLeft[0] + numLeft, &dataLeft[0] + numLeft));

    auto first2 = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(&segmentIdsRight[0], &dataRight[0]));
    auto last2 = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(&segmentIdsRight[0] + 3, &dataRight[0] + 3));

    int segmentIdsOutput[7];
    int dataOutput[7];
    int segmentsizesOutput[2];

    auto output = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(&segmentIdsOutput[0], &dataOutput[0]));

    auto comp = [](const auto& t1, const auto& t2){
        const int idl = thrust::get<0>(t1);
        const int idr = thrust::get<0>(t2);

        if(idl < idr) return true;
        if(idl > idr) return false;

        return thrust::get<1>(t1) < thrust::get<1>(t2);
    };

    auto outputend = thrust::set_difference(first1, last1, first2, last2, output, comp);

    int outputsize = thrust::distance(output, outputend);

    thrust::reduce_by_key(&segmentIdsOutput[0], &segmentIdsOutput[0] + outputsize, 
        thrust::make_constant_iterator(1), 
        thrust::make_discard_iterator(), &segmentsizesOutput[0]
    );

    std::cerr << "raw data output: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < outputsize; i++){
        std::cerr << " " << dataOutput[i];
    }
    std::cerr << "\n";

    std::cerr << "result segment sizes: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        std::cerr << " " << segmentsizesOutput[i];
    }
    std::cerr << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach is working now. Instead of discarding the unique segment ids and storing the reduced values in the output array, both outputs are saved to temporary storage. Then, the output array is initialized with zero to account for any empty segments, and the key-value-pairs are used to set the segment sizes at the correct positions.

```
int uniqueIds[7];
int reducedCounts[7];

int numUnique = thrust::distance(
    &uniqueIds[0],
    thrust::reduce_by_key(
        &segmentIdsOutput[0], 
        &segmentIdsOutput[0] + outputsize, 
        thrust::make_constant_iterator(1), 
        &uniqueIds[0], 
        &reducedCounts[0]
    ).first
);

thrust::fill(&segmentsizesOutput[0], &segmentsizesOutput[0] + 2, 0);

thrust::for_each_n(
    thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(&uniqueIds[0], &reducedCounts[0])),
    numUnique,
    [&] (auto tup){
        segmentsizesOutput[thrust::get<0>(tup)] = thrust::get<1>(tup);
    }
);
```